# Shure SM91 problem

Tags: microphones, equipment

I plugged my Shure SM91 direct into phantom power, not using a pre-amp, with the 3 pin XLR. Can't find the pre-amp, so cannot check if the mic still works. But it certainly didn't then!

What is likely to have happened, and is it retrievable? It's a condenser boundary mic.

Comment: There's only half a tale here. I can't actually figure out what you did & what doesn't work. Bit of stream-of-consciousness going on ;))

Comment: @Tetsujin - quite simple - without the pre-amp available, I plugged the SM91 into a recording desk, with phantom power, and got no sound.. Wonder if the mic got fried, or whether it would still work when I find/buy a pre-amp.

Comment: Did you use some kind of adapter cable? I don’t think the SM91 will work at all without the preamp.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't realised how integral the pre was to the setup. It also doesn't have a standard XLR interface, so you'd have to have used a mickey mouse cable to connect it to regular phantom. Shure just says 'you must have one' - https://service.shure.com/s/article/sm91-preamp-replacement?language=en_US GearSpace says you'll fry it if you connect it direct, but provides no citation - https://gearspace.com/board/so-much-gear-so-little-time/967580-sm91-preamp-necessary.html

Comment: @Tetsujin - no, the cable is mini XLR into the mic, with standard 3 pin male XLR on the other, which obviously fits nicely into the input on a desk.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - it certainly didn't work at all without - I'm concerned that it won't work at all any more, anyway.

Comment: Shure says it's a 3-pin mini - https://service.shure.com/s/article/sm91-preamp-replacement?language=en_US It wouldn't be wise to ship it with a cable that could be used to wreck itself.

Comment: @Tetsujin - that makes good sense, I already read it, but it's written ambiguously, imo. And - the lead from the mic had a standard XLR - not sure why, though... True, the out end of the pre-amp terminates in male XLR, can't remember the input, and can't find pic thereof.

Answer (score 2):

You say "with the 3 pin XLR".   WHAT 3 pin XLR?

If you made up a special cable converting the supplied "miniature Switchcraft connectors" to XLR, and plugged it to a mic input with phantom power, here's at least one opinion that you will have "toasted the FET".

https://gearspace.com/board/so-much-gear-so-little-time/967580-sm91-preamp-necessary.html

Comment: Thanks. Since posting, I did some homework, and read that blog already. Doesn't sound too promising. I never used the SM91 with its supplied lead (2nd hand) maybe because the XLR didn't fit the pre-amp. Should have smelled a rat...

Comment: Conclusion is : frying a FET smells like rat.